# d3.scale doesn't work when offline?

Tags: d3.js

This doesn't work offline, it works just fine when internet connection is available :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>d3 SVG barchart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><!--Line A-->
    <script src="d3.js"></script>       
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var dataArray = [20, 40, 50, 60];
    var width=500;
    var height=500;

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

    var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([0, 60])
                     .range([0, width]);

    var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataArray)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d){
                                    return widthScale(d);
                                })
                    .attr("height", 50)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i){
                                return i*100;
                        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like the scale operation(s) of d3.js library doesn't work when I'm offline (or when Line A in is put in a comment block), why? Is there any d3.js version that works for offline user?

I enjoy snap.svg practices offline (I don't have private internet connection available), is there any way to do this with d3.js?

Comment: this library will load when internet connection is available `http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`..please include only one script you including `d3.js` then later `d3.min.js`

Comment: A JavaScript library (not only D3) will work offline if its path is correctly referenced.

Comment: @Cyril : originally, I only included the `<script src="d3.js"><script>`. Since it doesn't work, I tried to include the `<script src="d3.min.js"><script>` in a rather desperate attempt to make it work offline. No success though.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado : not in my case, I've tried this since yesterday. Simple enter-update-exit works, but when scale operation is involved, the code  never work.

Comment: And the library is in the same folder of the HTML file, right?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado : yes, of course the path to the library is correct. I've been glaring to it since yesterday. Once again : simple enter-update-exit works, but whenever scale operation is involved....problem.

Comment: Do you get any error in the JS console? Are you sure you downloaded the same version (v3) offline and not d3 v4 which renamed `d3.scale.linear() -> d3.scaleLinear()` among other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><!--Line A-->
    <script src="d3.js"></script>       
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
```

Download

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Refer correctly to it locally and remove:

```
    <script src="d3.js"></script>       
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.download and add d3.v3.min.js in asset folder

2.remove

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><!--Line A-->
<script src="d3.js"></script>       
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
```

3.add

```
 <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

then d3 graph will work in offline .